# AS3 how to draw line along box2d distancejoint

Tags: actionscript-3, line, box2d

is there anyone who knows how to draw a line along the box2d distancejoint  ??

```
var distanceJointDef:b2DistanceJointDef = new b2DistanceJointDef();
```

PLEASE HELP !!!

Comment: A 'def' variable is the definition used to create the joint. You would need to use the created joint itself to draw lines for. Usually you can use GetAnchor1 and GetAnchor2 to get the points.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used the `b2DistanceJoinDef`, but by [glancing at the documentation](http://personal.boristhebrave.com/permanent/09/Box2DFlashAS3Docs/Box2D/Dynamics/Joints/b2DistanceJointDef.html) it looks like there are two vector points for you to draw a line between, something as simple as:

```
var start:b2Vec2 = distanceJointDef.localAnchor1;
var end:b2Vec2 = distanceJointDef.localAnchor2;
var line:b2Vec2 = end.Subtract(start);

var shape:Shape = new Shape();

shape.x = start.x;
shape.y = start.y;

shape.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xFF0000);
shape.graphics.lineTo(line.x, line.y);

stage.addChild(shape);
```

I assume you will need to scale the x and y values down to an appropriate size (Box2D measures in metres).